# nodemon app crashed waiting for a file change before start

Tags: node.js, nodemon

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());


const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://Miles:Morales@cluster0.lic6t.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

So I pretty much keep getting a nodemon error and Im not sure as to why it keeps saying my useAndModify is an invalid option and I'm not sure as to why as this is the right way to do this code I've recheked many times and still cant find a reason as I keep getting this error Ill post the error down below. If you can notice whats wrong please tell me as i have no clue as to why this error is appearing

(node:16864) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
C:\Users\drago\OneDrive\Documents\Third Year College\DataRep\Pro\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:174
if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}` is an invalid option.`);
^

Error: `useFindAndModify` is an invalid option.
at Mongoose.set (C:\Users\drago\OneDrive\Documents\Third Year College\DataRep\Pro\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:174:48)
at file:///C:/Users/drago/OneDrive/Documents/Third%20Year%20College/DataRep/Pro/server/index.js:21:10
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:110:37)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

---

Here is the package.json
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"type":"module",
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon index.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^6.1.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.15"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });
```

Comment: Hi I have tried this and I'm still receiving this error